# resample dataframe for every hour

Tags: python

I want to resample the data in Sms ,call and Internet column by replacing the value by their mean for every hour.

Code 1 tried :

```
df1.reset_index().set_index('TIME').resample('1H').mean()
```

error:Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Code 2 tried:

```
df1['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIME'])
df1.CALL.resample('60min', how='mean')
```

error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
Dataframe:

```
    ID          TIME         SMS          CALL      INTERNET
0   1   2013-11-30 23:00:00 0.277204    0.273629    13.674575
1   1   2013-11-30 23:10:00 0.341536    0.058176    13.330858
2   1   2013-11-30 23:20:00 0.379427    0.054601    11.329552
3   1   2013-11-30 23:30:00 0.600781    0.218489    13.166163
4   1   2013-11-30 23:40:00 0.405565    0.134176    13.347791
5   1   2013-11-30 23:50:00 0.187700    0.080738    12.434744
6   1   2013-12-01 00:00:00 0.282651    0.135964    13.860353
7   1   2013-12-01 00:10:00 0.109826    0.056388    12.583463
8   1   2013-12-01 00:20:00 0.348638    0.053438    12.644995
9   1   2013-12-01 00:30:00 0.138375    0.054062    12.251733
10  1   2013-12-01 00:40:00 0.054062    0.163803    11.292642


df1.dtypes
ID            int64
TIME         object
SMS         float64
CALL        float64
INTERNET    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use parameter `on` in [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

> **on** : string, optional
>
> For a DataFrame, column to use instead of index for resampling. Column must be datetime-like.
> New in version 0.19.0.

```
df1['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['TIME'])
df = df1.resample('60min', on='TIME').mean()
print (df)
                     ID       SMS      CALL   INTERNET
TIME                                                  
2013-11-30 23:00:00   1  0.365369  0.136635  12.880614
2013-12-01 00:00:00   1  0.186710  0.092731  12.526637
```

Or add `set_index` for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df1['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['TIME'])
df = df1.set_index('TIME').resample('60min').mean()
```

Comment: thank you @jezrael. It works!! but in my case, even the ID column is being averaged out.                                                                            
                                        ID       SMS      CALL   INTERNET
TIME                                                           
2013-11-30 23:00:00  5000.624339  2.829674  1.239895  62.598992

Comment: You can use `df = df1.drop('ID', axis=1).resample('60min', on='TIME').mean()` or `df = df1.drop('ID', axis=1).set_index('TIME').resample('60min').mean()`

Comment: I need Time as a df column and not index. Also I need ID column to be present in df.