# How to plot data per hour, grouped by days?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Background: from a large `DataFrame` I filtered out entries for `year=2013`, `month=June`, week of the 3rd - 9th (Monday to Sunday). Then, I grouped the data by `day`, `hour`, and `user_type`, and pivoted the table to get a `DataFrame` which looks like:

```
   Day  Hour  Casual  Registered  Casual_percentage
0  3    0     14      19          42.42
1  3    1     8       8           50.00
2  3    2     1       3           25.00
3  3    3     2       1           66.67
4  3    4     1       3           25.00
5  3    5     1       17          5.56
.  .    .     .       .           .
```

For each day I have 24 hours so for day 4 (Tuesday), the data starts like:

```
.  .    .     .       .           .  
21 3    21    32      88          26.67
22 3    22    26      64          28.89
23 3    23    23      30          43.40
24 4    0     10      11          47.62
25 4    1     1       5           16.67
26 4    2     1       1           50.00
.  .    .     .       .           .
```

How can I plot `Casual` and `Registered` variables per `Hour`, for each of the 7 `Day`s? Would I need to create 7 different plots and align them in 1 figure?

Current code. I feel I'm way off. I also tried to create a [second x-axis](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html) (for `Days`) using the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html).

```py
def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax1.set(xlabel='Hours', ylabel='Total # of trips started')

ax1.plot(data.Hour, data.Casual, color='g')
ax1.plot(data.Hour, data.Registered, color='b')


"""This part is trying to create the 2nd x-axis (Days)"""
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
#offset the bottom spine
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes', -.5))
make_patch_spines_invisible(ax2)
#show bottomm spine
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
ax2.set_xlabel("Days")


plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

[End goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPV7m.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should be easier if you work on `datetime` objects rather than `Day`, `Hour` strings.
This way, you'll be able to use [date tick locators and formatters](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)
 along with [major and minor ticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html).

Even if you didn't mention it, I assume you can use `pandas` to deal with dataframes.
I created a new dataframe by copying many times data you provided and cutting some of them (this is not so important).
Here I rebuilt dates from infos you provided, but I suggest to work directly on them (I suppose the original dataframe has some kind of date-like field in it).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv("mydataframe.csv")
df["timestamp"] = "2013-06-" + df["Day"].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + "-" + df["Hour"].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format="%Y-%m-%d-%H")


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax1.set(xlabel='', ylabel='Total # of trips started')
ax1.plot(df["timestamp"], df.Casual, color='g')
ax1.plot(df["timestamp"], df.Registered, color='b')

ax1.xaxis.set(
    major_locator=mdates.DayLocator(),
    major_formatter=mdates.DateFormatter("\n\n%A"),
    minor_locator=mdates.HourLocator((0, 12)),
    minor_formatter=mdates.DateFormatter("%H"),
)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: formatted dataframe]

Comment: Yes the `DataFrame` (already holding values for '13 June 3-9) has a `datetime` variable `s_datetime` and I did: `data = df.groupby([df['s_timedate'].dt.day, df['s_timedate'].dt.hour, df.user_type]).agg({'hubway_id':'count'})` to get the count per day & hour. But if I understand correctly I should get the count keeping the datetime variable having columns: `date_time`, `Casual`, `Registered` ?

Comment: @Bn.F76  Yes, you should keep datetime variable. In order to achieve a time grouping, you could also use pandas `resample`. Look for example at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344899/resample-dataframe-for-every-hour

Comment: Thank you! Last thing, what does `mdates.DateFormatter("\n\n%A")`  mean ? I know `%H` gets hour,  `%Y` year, etc. but I don't understand your expression and I want to play around so I get ticks for every hour within the 24h window

Comment: @Bn.F76 in `"\n\n%A"`, `\n\n` simply put weekdays two lines below hour ticks, while `%A`  gets "Weekday as locale’s full name". Look at http://strftime.org/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is ordered by index (e.g., 0 - 24 is day 3, 25 - 48 is day 4, etc.) you can plot the index values rather than hours in your code:

```
ax1.plot(data.index.values, df.Casual, color='g')
ax1.plot(data.index.values, df.Registered, color='b')
```

This will yield a graph similar to what you're looking for as an end product (note I used fake data):

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately for some weeks there is no data for certain hours so the index approach is not exact / robust.

Comment: So then yeah you need to reformat your data as the other answer mentioned. Working with separate columns for hours, days, months, etc. is no bueno and you ought to concatenate them into a datetime object.