# How to plot data per weekday and hour in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seaborn

I want to plot my data of a timeseries (of bikes) by showing the mean of number of bikes per hour and weekday.

here is an extract of the initial data :

```
date                    nb_bike     
2019-09-20 12:00:00     15  
2019-09-20 13:00:00     10  
2019-09-20 14:00:00     17  
2019-09-20 15:00:00     12  
2019-09-20 16:00:00     24
```

I computed this mean per weekday and hour that way :

```
data_b = data_b_init.groupby([data_b_init.index.weekday.rename('wkday'),data_b_init.index.hour.rename('hour')]).mean()
data_b = data_b.reset_index()
```

So I want to plot these data (here an extract) :

```
data_b

wkday   hour    nb_bike_mean    
0   0   0.44    
0   1   0.11    
0   2   0.00    
0   3   0.11    
0   4   0.00    
0   5   0.67    
0   6   0.78    
0   7   6.44    
0   8   13.83   
0   9   9.78
```

I would like to do something like that : [How to plot data per hour, grouped by days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368411/how-to-plot-data-per-hour-grouped-by-days/56368605)
(especially like this graph : 
[image]

but I don't find how to do it by keeping just weekdays and hours information and not days.

For example, I tried this code :

```
sns.lineplot(x='hour',y='nb_bike_mean',data=data_b, hue='wkday')
```

but it isn't what I want, because I want both wkday and hour on x axis.

Do you know a way to plot with 2 levels on x axis ?

Or better, to have wkday and hour recognized as datetime and to join them as index ?

Comment: Actually, if you plot `data_b` before reset_index()` you would get the graph, sans the tick xaxis labels

Comment: I also tried of course, but I don't know why, I just got a graph with no line at all...

Comment: When I keep wkday and hour as index, the format of index is MultiIndex (I get that when I print the index : MultiIndex([(0,  0),
            (0,  1),
            (0,  2),... (6, 22),
            (6, 23)],
           names=['j_sem', 'heure'], length=168)