# Plotting data from dataframe column using matplotlib- specific start index and number of datapoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00374/energydata_complete.csv

I have this data set that shows energy data logged every 10 minutes for 4.5 months in Chievres, Belgium.

I am only interested in displaying the ‘date’, ‘Appliances’, ‘lights’, and ‘T_out’ in a dataframe. The relevant code is below.

```
df=pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00374/energydata_complete.csv')
df=df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,21]]
df.head(5)
```

[(I'd show the df but I'm new to SO and don't know how to include output in a question, sorry :) )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3LVX.png)

I'd like to create a plot using matplotlib that shows only the lights data for 4 days to see if there is a correlation between daytime and nighttime energy usage. I want to start with ‘2016-01-12 06:00:00’ am to have an accurate representation of a day.

I know that the data for one day is equal to 144 data points since each point is recorded every 10 minutes, so for four days it is 576 data points.

```
 fig = plt.figure()
 fig.plot(df['lights'])
```

This is literally the only code I have so far and I know it isn't even remotely correct lol.
How can I graph the relevant data from the 'lights' column in the dataframe and limit the plot to 576 data points?

Comment: It's probably best to be grouping by datetime, have a look at this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368411/how-to-plot-data-per-hour-grouped-by-days

Answer (score 0):

Update: The following code works although if I am being perfectly honest I am not sure why or how

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(1,1)
lights= df[df['date']=='2016-01-12 06:00:00'].index[0]
axes.plot(df.iloc[lights:lights+144*4,0], df.iloc[lights:lights+144*4,2], color='g', alpha=0.5)
xticks=np.arange(0,144*4,36)
```

I don't really understand the parameters of the `df.iloc[]` function